# Cannot Get RockMargin For Extension Visual C++ 2012 Express

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-extensions, vsix

In a video I watched, someone used an extension in Visual Studio called [RockMargin](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/1b0d7360-40dd-447e-8bef-90e2cf52f683).  Basically what this extension does is it adds a bar next to the scroll bar that shows a minimized version of all of your code.  I downloading the VSIX file and when opening it, it threw this:

> This extension is not installable on any currently installed products.

This is very odd considering that I have Visual C++ 2012 Express installed on my computer.  Even stranger is that in the install log, it states that it finds the program, but seemingly proceeds to ignore it.  Here is the full install log:

> 10/12/2015 2:04:37 PM - Microsoft VSIX Installer
>
> 10/12/2015 2:04:37 PM - -------------------------------------------
>
> 10/12/2015 2:04:37 PM - Initializing Install...
>
> 10/12/2015 2:04:37 PM - Extension Details...
>
> 10/12/2015 2:04:37 PM -   Identifier      : 2fde119c-c777-469c-b39c-628d79ca8fd2
>
> 10/12/2015 2:04:37 PM -   Name            : RockMargin
>
> 10/12/2015 2:04:37 PM -   Author          : Kitty
>
> 10/12/2015 2:04:37 PM -   Version         : 1.3.1
>
> 10/12/2015 2:04:37 PM -   Description     : Reincarnation of famous RockScroll extension for Visual Studio 2010/2012/2013
>
> 10/12/2015 2:04:37 PM -   Locale          : en-US
>
> 10/12/2015 2:04:37 PM -   MoreInfoURL     : http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/1b0d7360-40dd-447e-8bef-90e2cf52f683
>
> 10/12/2015 2:04:37 PM -   InstalledByMSI  : False
>
> 10/12/2015 2:04:37 PM -   SupportedFrameworkVersionRange : [4.0]
>
> 10/12/2015 2:04:37 PM -
>
> 10/12/2015 2:04:37 PM -   Supported Products :
>
> 10/12/2015 2:04:37 PM -       Microsoft.VisualStudio.IntegratedShell
>
> 10/12/2015 2:04:37 PM -           Version : [10.0]
>
> 10/12/2015 2:04:37 PM -       Microsoft.VisualStudio.IntegratedShell
>
> 10/12/2015 2:04:37 PM -           Version : [11.0]
>
> 10/12/2015 2:04:37 PM -       Microsoft.VisualStudio.IntegratedShell
>
> 10/12/2015 2:04:37 PM -           Version : [12.0]
>
> 10/12/2015 2:04:37 PM -
>
> 10/12/2015 2:04:37 PM -   References      :
>
> 10/12/2015 2:04:37 PM -
>
> 10/12/2015 2:04:37 PM - Searching for applicable products...
>
> 10/12/2015 2:04:37 PM - Found installed product - Microsoft Visual Studio Express 2012 for Windows Desktop
>
> 10/12/2015 2:04:37 PM - Found installed product - Global Location
>
> 10/12/2015 2:04:37 PM - VSIXInstaller.NoApplicableSKUsException: This extension is not installable on any currently installed products.
>
> at VSIXInstaller.App.InitializeInstall()
>
> at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.InnerInvoke()
>
> at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()

I would really enjoy to have this extension installed to aid in programming efficiency.  Any help is appreciated!

Comment: The Express Edition is limited, and doesn't allow all extensions. Have you considered Visual Studio 2015 Community Edition?

Comment: @BoPersson I have not, but it even if I did download VS2015 Community Edition, RockMargin does not support it.  Looks like the only way to get RockMargin is to pay money.  :(  Oh well, thanks anyway!

Comment: [RockMargin](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=K1tty.RockMargin) apparently supports VS 2012, 2013, 2015, 2017. That means the Community Editions are supported, too. Although I'm not sure, why anyone would still want it, as the features the extension offers come out of the box with Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not 100% certain as to when this was introduced directly into VS, but with VS 2013 onward (maybe earlier), this functionality is build in. You just need to change the code editor's Scroll Bars feature to use "Map Mode" instead of "Bar Mode", via the Tools.Options dialog. Specifically, if you navigate to the "Text Editor"\"All Languages"\"Scroll Bars" category in the "Tools Options" dialog, you'll see an option called "Use map mode for vertical scroll bar". Set that, and you should be good to go.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is just a feature in VS 2013 and on.